# Square in zeroes matrix using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, boolean

How can memory save memory space during generating binary `tf.bool` attention mask, that contains only a square of ones and others are zeros. Now I'm using `tf.matmul()` of two bool tensors converted to `tf.float32` that generate a square of ones in the right down corner.

```
attention_mask = tf.constant([ 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ])
attention_mask = tf.matmul(
    attention_mask[..., tf.newaxis],
    attention_mask[..., tf.newaxis],
    transpose_b=True,
)
```

Exist a logical (bool) variant of `tf.matmul` or some other way of efficiently doing this?

## EDIT

With using SparseTensor it's not working too.

```
x = tf.random.normal([1, 10, 64], dtype=tf.float32)
l = tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(1, 32)
m = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[8, 8], [8, 9], [9, 8], [9, 9]], values=[1, 1, 1, 1], dense_shape=[10, 10])

l(x, x, x, return_attention_scores=True, attention_mask=m)
```

Comment: Have you tried using sparse tensors ?

Comment: I don't know if `tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention` accepts as `attention_mask` sparse tensor. Here is docs about it: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MultiHeadAttention

Comment: @AloneTogether Attempt to convert a value (<tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor object at 0x283486370>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'>) to a Tensor.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @AloneTogether
 See above.

Comment: Yeah it will probably not work with the default `MultiHeadAttention` layer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242271/discussion-between-bc-martin-kubovcik-and-alonetogether).